In Linux, need. I guess via ffmpeg or similar solution, to accept an video input, merge a graphic image, and output the video to a specific monitor?
In Linux need. I guess via ffmpeg or similar solution, to accept an video input, merge a graphic image, and output the video to a specific monitor?  This is allow displaying an information banner over a live video feed.  The graphic of course would have a transparent background for the most part.
Looking at the ffmpeg examples this can be done with existing video files, but ffmpeg should accept live video as both an input and generated result as output of video, no?
My Linux system can definitely see the connected camera...
# v4l2-ctl --list-devices
USB Video: USB Video (usb-0000:01:00.0-1.1):
        /dev/video0
        /dev/video1
        /dev/media0

But I cannot seem to get the right configuration to be able to read the video data?
~# ffmpeg -f v4l2 -list_formats all -i /dev/video1
ffmpeg version 7.0.2-3ubuntu1 Copyright (c) 2000-2024 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 14 (Ubuntu 14.2.0-2ubuntu1)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr --extra-version=3ubuntu1 --toolchain=hardened --libdir=/usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu --incdir=/usr/include/aarch64-linux-gnu --arch=arm64 --enable-gpl --disable-stripping -                                                                                       -disable-libmfx --disable-omx --enable-gnutls --enable-libaom --enable-libass --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcdio --enable-libcodec2 --enable-libdav1d --enable-libflite --enable-libfontconfig --enable-l                                                                                       ibfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libglslang --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libharfbuzz --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libmysofa --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopenmpt --enable-libopus                                                                                        --enable-librubberband --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-l                                                                                       ibwebp --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libxvid --enable-libzimg --enable-openal --enable-opencl --enable-opengl --disable-sndio --disable-libvpl --enable-libdc1394 --enable-libdrm --enable-                                                                                       libiec61883 --enable-chromaprint --enable-frei0r --enable-ladspa --enable-libbluray --enable-libcaca --enable-libdvdnav --enable-libdvdread --enable-libjack --enable-libpulse --enable-librabbitmq --en                                                                                       able-librist --enable-libsrt --enable-libssh --enable-libsvtav1 --enable-libx264 --enable-libzmq --enable-libzvbi --enable-lv2 --enable-sdl2 --enable-libplacebo --enable-librav1e --enable-pocketsphinx                                                                                        --enable-librsvg --enable-libjxl --enable-shared
  libavutil      59.  8.100 / 59.  8.100
  libavcodec     61.  3.100 / 61.  3.100
  libavformat    61.  1.100 / 61.  1.100
  libavdevice    61.  1.100 / 61.  1.100
  libavfilter    10.  1.100 / 10.  1.100
  libswscale      8.  1.100 /  8.  1.100
  libswresample   5.  1.100 /  5.  1.100
  libpostproc    58.  1.100 / 58.  1.100
[video4linux2,v4l2 @ 0xaaaac16cea80] ioctl(VIDIOC_G_INPUT): Inappropriate ioctl for device
[in#0 @ 0xaaaac169ea60] Error opening input: Inappropriate ioctl for device
Error opening input file /dev/video1.
Error opening input files: Inappropriate ioctl for device

Just to test the hardware, I installed OBS (Open Broadcast System) Studio.  OBS can see the camera input just fine, it discovers the camera input is set to 1080p60.
